# UIView transitionWIthView simple change image animation — how to explicitly mention ‘self’

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Background**

I have an iPhone app I wrote in ObjectiveC about eight years ago that works just fine. However it is five years since I last updated it (or indeed did any iOS work) and Apple is threatening to throw it off the App Store unless I submit an update. It is of use to a niche audience and I wish to keep it there. I have managed to deal with most of the “issues” raised (deprecated methods etc.) but there is one “Semantic Issue” regarding an image flip animation that I cannot seem to find an answer to.

**Semantic Issue**

> Block implicitly retains ‘self’; explicitly mention ‘self’ to indicate this is the intended behaviour.

**Code that generates this issue**

I have marked the two lines that Xcode flags with  ⌫

```
if (segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:pictureView
                        duration:0.5
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                        animations:^{ pictureView.image = image;}  ⌫
                        completion:nil];
}
else
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:pictureView
                        duration:0.5
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                        animations:^{ pictureView.image = digImage;}   ⌫
                        completion:nil];
}
```

`pictureView` is the UIView which is an instance variable of the class associated with an IBOutlet.

This block of code is contained in a method `(IBAction)changeSegment` which first initializes two UIimages, `image` and `digImage`, to a pair of jpgs appropriate to the instance.

The idea — obvious, I am sure — is that on taping pictureView the image associated with it (initially a photo) is flipped (to a corresponding diagram); on tapping it again it is flipped back.

I can’t remember where I got the code originally (as I said, it works), but the animation section differs from examples I can find on the web and on [Apple’s Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transitionwithview). I tried throwing ‘selfs’ in everywhere I could think of, but, not really understanding the problem, was not too surprised that this failed.

**Question**

So how do I modify this code to “explicitly mention self”?

Comment: Also Apple recommends now not accessing ivars directly, you should use properties instead. Ivar should be used only in initializers

Comment: @Cy-4AH Any suggestion on how I would do that in this case?

Comment: @Cy-4AH Ah. Think I see now, as explained in my response to your comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly means, that written `pictureView.image = image;` but will be compiled as: `self.pictureView.image = image;`

So just replace it to how it will be compiled, to make compiler sure, that you know that you are passing `self` inside of block and you doesn't care about possible retain cycled caused by passing self inside of block.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had tried that, but got an error: Property 'pictureView' not found on object of type 'GroundsDetailViewController *'; did you mean to access instance variable 'pictureView'? . GroundsDetailViewController is the class.

Comment: @David you can access ivars with `self->pictureView` syntax, but better instead is to add properties in classes

Comment: Ah... Blown a few cobwebs off now. Have solved the problem by transferring the "pictureView.image = img;" to a setImage() method, and then calling this in the transitionWithView:pictureView animation as [self setImage: image]; I presume this uses a property, as you suggested in your comment to my question.